# Rounded corners white background frame

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, rounded-corners

I am new to Cocoa and need some help.
I got rounded corners layer in my app, but I can't set corners to transparent.

[image: Image how it looks]
Here's my code

```
    guard let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first else { return }
    let effect = NSVisualEffectView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    effect.blendingMode = .withinWindow
    effect.state = .active
    effect.material = .dark
    effect.wantsLayer = true

    effect.layer?.cornerRadius = 15.0
    effect.layer?.masksToBounds = true
    window.isOpaque = true
    window.backgroundColor = .clear
    window.contentView = effect
    window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    window.titleVisibility = .hidden
    window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
```

Trying everything possible for few good hours now, would really appreciate some help for begginer. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe consider adding `window.styleMask = .borderless`

Comment: Unfortunately same result :(

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: Replace the NSVisualEffectView with UIVisualEffectView because In swift 4 there is no NSVisualEffectView that's why try with?

Answer (score -1):

Within your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method make sure the window is transparent:

```
window.isOpaque = false
```

And your background color is clear:

```
window.backgroundColor = .clear
```

If `window.backgroundColor = .clear` does not work, then try

```
window.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 1, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
```

It's unclear by your question what method your code is in. If it is in the wrong method then, it may not be recognized properly (without necessarily throwing an error).